# How to include the linux headers inside the Android NDK cpp file?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

**I'm using Android Studio 4.1 and NDK 21.3.6528147.**

Can I include the following linux headers in Android NDK cpp file?

I copied all the headers from this link: https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/arm64/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r0.88/fs/block_dev.c

**src/main/cpp/test.cpp**

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/mm.h>
#include <linux/fcntl.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/kmod.h>
#include <linux/major.h>
#include <linux/device_cgroup.h>
#include <linux/highmem.h>
#include <linux/blkdev.h>
#include <linux/backing-dev.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/blkpg.h>
#include <linux/magic.h>
#include <linux/buffer_head.h>
#include <linux/swap.h>
#include <linux/pagevec.h>
#include <linux/writeback.h>
#include <linux/mpage.h>
#include <linux/mount.h>
#include <linux/uio.h>
#include <linux/namei.h>
#include <linux/log2.h>
#include <linux/cleancache.h>
#include <linux/dax.h>
#include <linux/badblocks.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include "internal.h"
```

**When building the project, the following error occurred:**

```
/testproject/app/src/main/cpp/test.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'linux/init.h' file not found
```

**What is needed in order to make all the above headers work in Android NDK cpp?**

Thanks.